# How can I remove all lines that don't contain numbers in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How can I accomplish removing lines without numbers in Notepad++?

Example

```
username:password [Remove Entire Line]
E1x3ample:se9c5rui6ty [Keep this Line]
Razar:beurself [Remove All Line]
Best:Stars [Remove Entire Line]
B1eYou4self:M1a9gic [Keep this Line]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the find and replace function in Notepad++.  You need to set the Replace function to use Regular Expressions and check the box matching `.` to a newline, then use this as your "Find what" criteria:

```
^\D*$.
```

I'm no regex expert, but basically this uses `^` to start at the beginning of a line, `\D` matches to non-digit characters, `*` matches multiple times, `$` continues to the end of the line, and `.` matches the newline characters (otherwise it removes the text but leaves the empty line behind).